# child method gets called before parent's method response

Tags: angular

I have a parent component and a child.
The parent component has a method that subscribes to an observable. This response is passed through input to the child in order to show the response on UI.

The problem is that the child component is rendered BEFORE I get the response from the parent.

How can I solve this wihtout using a service?

My ouptut is: 2, 1

parent component

```
ngOnInit() {
  parentMethod();
}

    parentMethod() {
      this.service.serviceMethod.subscribe(response: MyObject[] => {
          myVar = response;
          console.log('1')
       }) 
     }
```

child component

```
<app-child-component [myVarInput]="myVar"> </app-child-component>

@Input() myVarInput: MyObject[];
ngOnInit() {
    console.log('2')
    console.log(this.myVarInput)
}
```

Comment: In your `Parent method` you called api(Asynchronous) If I'm not wrong and the `Child method` you print the value in `ngOnInit`. It seems to be fine. What is your issue. Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to set myvar and mayvarInput variables as observable

example :

html file :

```
<app-child [myVarInput$]="myVar$"></app-child>
```

ts file :

```
myvar$:observable<any>;

this.service.serviceMethod.subscribe(response: MyObject[] => {
          myVar$ = response;
          console.log('1')
       })
```

childcomponent ts file :

```
myVarInput$ :observable<any>
```

Answer (score 0):

The initialization of your child-component is not dependent on the Input() variable.

This is happening here:

1. Parent components onInit() is called
2. Child components onInit() is called (writing 2 on console)
3. The Observable gets resolved (writing 1 on console)
4. Then the Input() of the child component will be set and child components onChanges() will be called

Angular does not wait for Input() variables to be set before rendering your component. You have to make sure the component is able to handle empty fields.

Comment: that is true, I've called ngOnChanges and I do have the input value, but the html elements of child component that are using the input values aren't renderd again, so I always have them empty

Comment: Change detection should kick in and rerender on Input change. Can you recreate the issue on stackblitz or edit your question so we can see the html template of your child component?